# Video-capture vertical output iOS

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, gpuimage, pbjvision

I am trying to capture video with [PBJVision](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision).

I set up camera like this

```
vision.cameraMode = PBJCameraModeVideo;
vision.cameraOrientation = PBJCameraOrientationPortrait;
vision.outputFormat = PBJOutputFormatWidescreen;
```

And this produces output `1280x720` where `1280` is `width`.

Setting orientation to `Landscape` ROTATES the stream.

I have been trying to record video with [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage), and there I can

```
videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720
cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

_movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:_movieURL size:CGSizeMake(720.0, 1280.0)];
```

So that i get vertical output.

I would like to achieve vertical output for PBJVision, because I experience problems with GPUImage writing video to disk. (I will make another question for that).

What method/property of `AVFoundation` is responsible for giving the vertical output instead of horizontal?

Sorry for the question, I have been googling 2 days - can't find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I changed the output format to `vision.outputFormat = PBJOutputFormatPreset;` and I'm getting that portrait/vertical output.